# Nest authorization web page cropped on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, nest-api

The Nest Authorization Web Page had some updates recently.  Now, when displayed in Safari on a smaller screen, such as an iPhone 5S, it is cropped. I did verify that it looks correct on an iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

I am showing this same page in a WebViewController, and it suffers from the same issue.

[image: Nest Auth Web Page]